# How to measure CPU/GPU data transfer overhead in Metal

Tags: xcode, gpgpu, instruments, metal

We have been porting some of our CPU pipeline to Metal to speed up some of the slowest parts with success. However since it is only parts of it we are transferring data back and forth to the GPU and I want to know how much time this actually takes.

Using the frame capture in XCode it informs me that the kernels take around 5-20 ms each, for a total of 149.5 ms (all encoded in the same Command Buffer).
[image: XCode performance metrics]

Using Instruments I see some quite different numbers:
[image: Instruments trace]
The entire thing operations takes 1.62 seconds (Points - Code 1).
`MTLTexture replaceRegion` takes up the first 180 ms, followed with the CPU being stalled the next 660 ms at `MTLCommandBuffer waitUntilCompleted` (highlighted area), and then the last 800 ms gets used up in `MTLTexture getBytes` which maxes out that CPU thread.

Using the Metal instruments I'm getting a few more measurements, 46ms for "Compute Command 0", 460 ms for "Command Buffer 0", and 210 ms for "Page Off". But I'm not seeing how any of this relates to the workload.

The closest thing to an explanation of "Page off" I could find is this:

> Texture Page Off Data (Non-AGP)
>
> The number of bytes transferred for texture page-off operations. Under most conditions, textures are not paged off but are simply thrown away since a backup exists in system memory. Texture page-off traffic usually happens when VRAM pressure forces a page-off of a texture that only has valid data in VRAM, such as a texture created using the function glCopyTexImage, or modified using the functiona glCopyTexSubImage or glTexSubImage.

[Source: XCode 6 - OpenGL Driver Monitor Parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGLDriverMonitorUserGuide/Glossary/Glossary.html)

This makes me think that it could be the part that copies the memory off the GPU, but then there wouldn't be a reason `getBytes` takes that long. And I can't see where the 149.5 ms from XCode should fit into the data from Instruments.

**Questions**

1. When exactly does it transfer the data? If this cannot be inferred from the measurements I did, how do I acquire those?
2. Does the GPU code actually only take 149.5 ms to execute, or is XCode lying to me? If not, then where is the remaining 660-149.5 ms being used?